# c = getchar() != EOF; prints 0 or 1

Tags: c, character, ascii

When i run this code it prints the dos 0 character(space) once, puts a space and prints dos 1 character(smiley face with white eyes and mouth).

[image]

```
int c = 0, b = 1;
printf("%c %c", c, b);
```

But when i run this code below the result is being printed twice. I either get 2 spaces or 2 smiley faces.

[image]

```
while(c != -1)
{
    c = getchar() != EOF;
    putchar(c);
}
```

Edit: My code doesnt have paranthesis so it compares every single entered character with EOF and assigns the result (0 or 1) to c and then prints c as a char. In order to prevent this, we can use paranthesis to force the program to do c = getchar() first and then compare that value with EOF.

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that a '\n' character is not equal to EOF. The '\n' is being read in as a second character.

Comment: I thought getchar just read one character and stopped reading. I guess the stream of characters dont stop. Can you give me a link where i can learn how does this thing work exactly? I want to learn. I am studying the book C programming language at the moment.

Comment: It does only read one character, but then your loop runs a second time and automatically reads in the next character.  [Here is the reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/). It explains that getchar() reads a character from stdin. You stdin input looks like "1\n" so in your first loop through it reads the 1, then in the next loop it reads the '\n'. If you change EOF to '\n' it will fix the issue.